# Regular Expression in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have many strings for creating tables en visual basic 2008 . Well, I need change the size of VARCHAR fields, so I am trying to replace any ocurrence of varchar with 2 digits in VARCHAR(100).

I am using the following code:

```
Dim pattern As String = "VARCHAR\([0-9]^2\)"
Dim replacement As String = "VARCHAR(100)"
Console.WriteLine("Regex: " + Regex.Replace(msAccessQuery, pattern, replacement))
```

But, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The code is inside of a VB.NET application, so I am using VB.NET ;)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2008's find/replace? Or writing VB.NET code? They're two different things and your question is confusing as a result.

Comment: I am writing VB.NET code, sorry the confusion.

Comment: '^2' doesn't mean 2 times in regular expressions, it means `^` Beginning of string/line, `2` means literal char `'2'`. Either `[0-9][0-9]` or `\d\d` or `\d{2}` as @AlexK recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2 digits:

```
VARCHAR\(\d{2}\)
```

For 1 or 2:

```
VARCHAR\(\d{1,2}\)
```

Prefix with `\b` to avoid `NVARCHAR`.